# System calls source code

Tags: system-calls, system-programming

C library provides functions such as write(),read(),open()...that we can use in our C program to make system calls. where can I find source code for these functions?

Comment: In the source code for the C library ;)  The one normally used on GNU/Linux systems is https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html

Comment: The book The C Programming Language 2nd Edition also known as K&R Book Discusses the implmentation of some of these implementations it is listed in Chapter 8

Answer (score 4):

These are syscalls and are implemented by the kernel. You can find both `read` and `write` in `fs/read_write.c`. All `read` and `write` does is to call their `ksys` version, for example `ksys_read` or `ksys_write`, as shown below.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)
{
    return ksys_read(fd, buf, count);
}
```

```
ssize_t ksys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    struct fd f = fdget_pos(fd);
    // ...
}
```

[`fs/read_write.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c#L609)

Answer (score 2):

There is good deep and detailed description about system call at kernel side in recent lwn article: http://lwn.net/Articles/604287/ .

Answer (score 1):

If you want source code for standard C library, look at the link @goldilocks provided.

If you want source code for linux system call, you must search through the linux source code. System call is defined in many locations of linux source. You can grep for string macro `SYSCALL_DEFINE`:

```
grep -r -n SYSCALL_DEFINE /path/to/linux_source
```

Some of them you can see [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/sys.c).

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

After GNU's libc, you can look at source code for other libc implementions:

[Musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/) has source code on-line for browsing: most system calls are [in here](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/unistd).

Someone has put [Diet Libc into github.](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc)  It's noted as unofficial, though.